# PromQL find total request in last minute?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

Hello I am new to PromQL . I am trying to add alert in Grafana using PromQL 'Create Alert when requests count for last one minute greater than 50 and status_code is not 200'

I am trying to achieve using

```
sum_over_time(http_requests_total{status_code!~'2.*'}[1m])
```

But facing error. Can anyone tell what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function instead of [sum_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time), since the `http_requests_total` is a [counter metric](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter). This metric type starts from zero when the app starts and then increases over time by counting the number of requests **since the service start**.

For example, the following query returns the number of requests with non-200 status code over the last hour:

```
increase(http_requests_total{status_code!="200"}[1h])
```

P.s. Prometheus can return unexpected results from `increase` function. For example, it can return fractional results when applied to a counter with only integer values such as `http_requests_total`. This is [known issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). If you want obtaining exact values from `increase()` function, then try VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It provides the `increase()` function, which works as most users expect. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) for details.